# PHP OOP print a variable which has value inside the function but call from outside to be print

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to *print* a *variable* which has the value *inside* the function but it's called from outside the function to be print in object oriented programming in PHP

Let's explain by example

My class looks like as:

```
class my {
   public $a;

   public function myFunc(){
       $name = "fahad";
       echo $this->a;
   }

}
```

It should print the value of `$name` when the function is call, as I am trying:

```
$class = new my();
$class->a = '$name';
$class->myFunc();
```

But it did't work and print the result as:

```
$name
```

I want it should print the value of variable `$name` which is **inside** the function

How it can be possible?

Thank You.

Comment: This is a bad idea. It violates abstraction. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: because i don't want to heavy my class functions and some data want to call from outside the function

Comment: @ShiraNai7 answer solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to do this, but it's usually considered bad practice.

```
class my {
   public $a;

   public function myFunc(){
       $name = "fahad";
       echo ${$this->a};
   }
}

$class = new my();
$class->a = 'name';
$class->myFunc();
```

Output:

```
fahad
```

Comment: Thank You very much this solved my biggest problem that is it what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function, you can make a check:

```
public function myFunc(){
    if($this->a == '$name'){
        $name = 'fahad';
        echo $name;
    }else echo $this->a;
}
```