# PHP MYSQL OOP Print the values of table rows which is called from outside variable to be print

Tags: php, mysql, oop

My PHP class function looks something like as when **fetching** data from *database table*:

```
class my {
   public $a;

   public function myFunc(){
       $query = mysql_query("select name,loc,info from stores");
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
           extract($row);
            echo $this->a;
       }
   }
}
```

I want that it should print the result of that rows of table which are called when creating object of the class and calling class method as:

```
$class = new my();
$class->a = '<h1>$name</h1>';
$class->a .= '<p>$loc</p>';
$class->myFunc();
```

But it did't gives proper result and print as:

```
$name
$loc
$name
$loc
$name
$loc
...
```

I want it should print the values of these variable which are actually rows of table and result should be something looking like as:

```
london store
london near the big mall, england
PK world wide store
F-5 street near the new G-T road london
...
```

How it can be possible?

Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP OOP print a variable which has value inside the function but call from outside to be print](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023628/php-oop-print-a-variable-which-has-value-inside-the-function-but-call-from-outsi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'<h1>$name</h1>'` and `'<p>$loc</p>'` are just a plain [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). The variable references inside them won't get evaluated by `echo`.

**You can return the items and render them outside of the function:**

```
class my {
   public function myFunc(){
       $query = mysql_query("select name,loc,info from stores");

       $items = array();
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $items[] = $row;
       }

       return $items;
   }
}

$class = new my();
$items = $class->myFunc();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo "<h1>{$item['name']}</h1><p>{$item['loc']}</p>";
}
```

**If you insist on rendering from within the function you can pass in an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):**

```
class my {
    public $renderer; 

    public function myFunc(){
        $query = mysql_query("select name,loc,info from stores");

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
             call_user_func($this->renderer, $row);
        }
    }
}

$class = new my();

$class->renderer = function ($row) {
    extract($row);
    echo "<h1>$name</h1><p>$loc</p>";
};

$class->myFunc();
```

---

I've used double quoted strings in the code. See [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) to learn the difference or see [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: the second one is the solution of my question. **Thank You**